# ArcMap 10.5 and Python Clear Cache?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, cache

I am running a python script from within ArcMap 10.5 and have always noticed that when I need to rerun the script in the same session, I get either an error or python goes to the next line showing just a ">>>". This happens more often on successful runs, but if the script fails because of syntax or data source issue, I can rerun it and it'll be fine. I often have to close out of my MXD and reopen it in order to run the script. It seems when it runs successfully, that there is something left open or the cache needs to be cleared in order for it to run again.

The errors that I get are random and are simply solved by closing the MXD and reopening.

Is there a way that I can clear the cache or force Arc to stop all background processes (if any are running) in Python?

```
import arcpy
from State_Dictionary import st_list_tup

# DEFINE VARIABLES
mxd  = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df   = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
lyr5 = arcpy.mapping.Layer("Counties")

lyr2  = arcpy.mapping.Layer("Otolaryngologists to Primary Care Physicians")
lyr3  = arcpy.mapping.Layer("Otolaryngologists")

for County in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if County.name == "Counties":
        lyr5 = County

for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
    if layer.name == "Otolaryngologists to Primary Care Physicians":
        lyr2 = layer
    if layer.name == "Otolaryngologists":
        lyr3 = layer

st_abbr       = "STATE_ABBR = '{}'"
Automate      = "Auto_State = '{}'"
count_lyr     = "STATE_NAME = '{}'"

for layer in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)[0:13]:

lyr2.visible  = False
lyr3.visible  = False    

for state, fname in st_list_tup:

    layer.visible = True
    layer.definitionQuery = Automate.format(state)

    # CREATE SELECTION LAYER AND WHERE CLAUSE
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(County,"NEW_SELECTION", count_lyr.format(fname))

    # ZOOM TO STATE SELECTION THEN CLEAR SELECTION
    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()

    # CLEAR SELCTION
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(County, "CLEAR_SELECTION")

    # DEFINITION QUERIES
    lyr5.definitionQuery = count_lyr.format(fname)

    print lyr2.definitionQuery, lyr3.definitionQuery, lyr4.definitionQuery

    # UPDATE MAP ELEMENTS
    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        if elm.name == "Title":
            elm.text = "{}".format(layer)

    for elm in arcpy.mapping.ListLayoutElements(mxd, "TEXT_ELEMENT"):
        if elm.name == "Subtitle":
            elm.text = "{}".format(fname)

    # EXPORT MAP SELECTION TO PNG IMAGE
    arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, r"C:\Data Projects\AMA (43.1GB)\Map Automation\Practice Maps\{}\{} {}.pdf".format(fname, fname, layer))

    # CLEAR DEFINITION QUERIES AND UPDATE MAP VIEW
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()


# DELETE LOCAL VARIABLES
del mxd, df, lyr3, lyr2, lyr4, lyr5

print "Success!"
```

Comment: there's something being held in memory from the first script. post the code and we can help more. can you post some of the errors you're seeing as well.

Comment: Not sure why it's not letting me post the entire code in formatted text.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your script:

```
from arcpy import env
env.overwriteOutput = True
```